# Are there any related theorems that can determine whether a parametric equation can eliminate parameters and express it explicitly?

Tags: systems-of-equations

Can the following cycloid equation be transformed into the display form of $y = f (x)$ by eliminating parameters $\phi$?

\begin{equation}  
\left\{  
\begin{array}{**rcl**}
    x=r(\phi-\sin \phi)& \\
    y=r(1-\cos \phi) &   
\end{array}
\right.  
\end{equation}

I know that it can be easily reduced to the form of $x = f (y)$ and probably there is no explicit elementary function form of $y = f (x)$.

Are there any related theorems that can determine whether a parametric equation can eliminate parameters and express it explicitly?